# Use product view block in product list

Tags: blocks

I am trying to use a block from `catalog/product_view` in `catalog/product_list` but I can't get the block to render. Below is the code that I'm trying to call from `template/catalog/product/list.phtml`.

`<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('additional') ?>`

Comment: You have no kid called additional. Like you said yourself, they're different blocks, and while names like Bob and Alice are common, not every parent has a child with this names. Analogies aside, you need to define the additional block as child of the product list block in your template xml. This is explained in detail in [No Frills Magento Layout]( http://store.pulsestorm.net/products/no-frills-magento-layout) , which I cannot recommend often enough.

Comment: I added it to catalog.xml but I can't reference the product that is currently rendered.

Comment: It appears that using the Magento current product helper will work in my block. I'll look at implementing this later and let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

The block alias name `additional` stands for the block `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Attributes` which is responsible for showing additional data related to a product in a product view page.

If you inspect further about the block, you can see that, this block is not rendered directly inside product view page. Instead it is added to a block group `detailed_info` and then uses this block group to show the `additional` block.

With that said, let us look what are the steps that you need to take care in order to add this block in a product list page.

### 1.Add the block in product list page via layout update

You can do this using `local.xml` file. This is how the code looks like

File : `app\design\frontend\<package>/<theme>/layout/local.xml`

```
<layout>
    <catalog_category_default>
        <reference name="product_list">
            <block type="catalog/product_view_attributes" name="product.attributes" as="additional" template="catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml">
                <action method="addToParentGroup"><group>detailed_info</group></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_category_default>
</layout>
```

This will add the `product.attributes` block to the `product_list` block, but which uses the feature of `addToParentGroup`. Due to this `product.attributes` block can be rendered in the same way it is rendering in a product view block.

### 2. Render the Child Groups of `product_list` block

Since we added `product.attributes` block as group child of product list, we need to show the block by looping through group childs. You can do this like this.

File : `app\design\frontend\<package>/<theme>/template/catalog/product/list.phtml`

```
....
<?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): 
    ....
    <?php foreach ($this->getChildGroup('detailed_info', 'getChildHtml') as $alias => $html):?>
    <div class="box-collateral <?php echo "box-{$alias}"?>">
        <?php if ($title = $this->getChildData($alias, 'title')):?>
        <h2><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($title); ?></h2>
        <?php endif;?>
        <?php echo $html; ?>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach;?>
    ....
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Here you can see that, we are added the group child rendering code inside the `foreach` loop which is responsible for looping through each products in a category product list.

### 3.Register the product in each loop

Now in order to make the `product.attributes` block work, we need to register and unregister for each product loop. Why would it need ? The answer resides in `app\design\frontend\<package>/<theme>/template/catalog/product/view/attributes.phtml`. You can see below code there.

```
$_product = $this->getProduct();
```

This call is actaully carrying out by `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Attributes::getProduct()`. The method look like this.

```
public function getProduct()
{
    if (!$this->_product) {
        $this->_product = Mage::registry('product');
    }
    return $this->_product;
}
```

As you can see, the method get the product from `Mage::registry()`. So it is important that, we need to `Mage::register` the product which is currently being in the product list loop.

So inside `list.phtml`, under the foreach loop of product collection, before calling the group child blocks, you need to do this registration. It looks somewhat like this.

```
 <?php foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): 
     ...
     <?php
          Mage::unregister('product');
          Mage::register('product', $_product);
 <?php foreach; ?>
```

Hope that makes sense.